# Import/export wizard code page error

Tags: sql-server, import

Using the Import/Export Wizard, I ended up with an annoying problem:

> Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "pinNumber" cannot be processed because more than one code page (874 and 1252) are specified for it.

Looks like a different codepage (`SQL_Latin1_General_CI_AS` vs `Latin1_General_CI_AS`), so I changed those to match: `Latin1_General_CI_AS` for both.

However, the wizard still throws an error and detects two codepages - I even checked the tables and both source and destination show the same `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Plus, why are you trying to steal "pinNumber" ? :)

Comment: Is this between two instances of SQL Server on different hosts, or between two instances of SQL Server on the same host, or two databases on the same instance? SQL Server sets the code page (based on the Windows code page) for an instance when you install it, and AFAIK that can't be changed.

Comment: one is MSSQL 2005 and other is 2008 instance installed on the same serverbox.
Thing is i can import/export my other DB-s, only this one seems to have a problem.

Comment: *Columns* have collations associated with them -- changing the collation at a higher-up level only sets the *default* for new objects, it doesn't change existing objects. I'm pretty sure the columns still have different collations, and that's the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem with a flat file.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Have you tried a code page 1252 for the flat file? What about the "drop and recreate option" for the destination table?

Comment: In my case I had to change the server collation - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428685/how-to-change-server-collation-in-sql-server-2008-r2)

Answer (score 3):

Problem can be in field level as it was for me.

In a source database, a field in a table had a different collation in a varchar datatype.

If you choose **< database default>**  for collation property of the fields, the problem may be solved.